# passing custom objects or just ids

Tags: android, database, performance, memory

I've a sqllite database where I store some data with a picture.

In my MainActivity, I load this data to a List< CustomObject > and using a ArrayAdapter with ListView to display this informations. On Item click, I'm passing the item id to the DetailActivity and there I'm requesting the item data again from the sqllite database to display it.

I'm worried, because I don't know whats the best way on android.

Should I use less informations in the MainActivity (only id, title and the picture) and pass the ID to the DetailActivity or should I pass the complete CustomObject through my DetailActivity (so I don't have to access the database again)

I want the right combination of memory-usage and performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as showing data, may i suggest using a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)?
As far as data efficiency is concerned if you already create custom objects for your listView you could aswell pass it along,you should not only if the delay of clicking an item may create data inconsistencies,in which case you should do another query to make sure user always sees the most updated data.
Also as if you take efficiency heartedly you should not download data again,but only update/remove data when necesary,this ensures your user won't have to wait too long before doing another task,and will make your program more efficient

Comment: For displaying the data I've just written a custom adapter which uses a custom list layout. The database can only be accessed by the user, so there can't be inconsistencies. I thought about modifying my custom object class to implement parcelable interface, so I can put customkbjects to other views.

Comment: Creating a listView can be achieved with a cursor adapter aswell.If you want to pass your custom object with intents you should make sure it is serializable.

Comment: whats the benefit of using a cursor adapter?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are uses a globle list suppose you have 2 activities listactivity that is show your list view and detailactivity that is show the detail now you create another Activity called mBAseActivity here is your globle list.

Now both listactivity and detailactivity are inherited by mBAseActivity .

in list Activity you can fill the globle list and click on item using the position you can go detailactivity here you again use this globle list and fatch its data and show it .